# Cython advice for cppclass - Should I write cpp file and extern? Or should I write a python cppclass?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a large body of python code that I am wanting to optimize. There are a few routines that can be cythonized for a significant speedup. In order to port the code to cython in a less painful manner, it would be nice to use the `==` and `+` operators for a struct that I am defining.

To be clear, I am not interfacing with already existing c++ code, but rather I want to use c++ structs to be able to create arrays from these structs, but still use constructors, operators and the like.

Firstly, I have a question. Is there any way besides using `extern` to define operator overloading.

For example, in python like so

```py
cdef cppclass Foo:
    int bar
    Foo(int)
    bint operator==(Foo)
```

etc... (where would I even get to define the `==` operator?)

Or is it necessary to actually write c++ code and extern it in python (which seems quite verbose honestly).

e.g.
`foo.cpp`

```cpp
struct Foo{
    int bar;
    Foo(int b){bar = b;};
    bool operator == (Foo &other){
        if (bar == other.bar){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    };
};
```

and have accompanying extern code in python

```py
cdef extern from 'foo.cpp':
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        int bar
        Foo(int)
        bint operator==(Foo)
```

I find it a bit silly writing c++ code just to extern it into python. But if the support for c++ structs is not there in cython it might be the best option going forward? I have no idea what the "best practice" might be.

Another option I was considering is using cdef classes, but I am under the impression not to do so because

1. Operator overloading would be a slow python operation
2. I wouldn't be able to define an array of cdef classes

If I am wrong about this, please tell me.

Also, clearly I am not fluent in c++, so if there are symmantic (or syntactic) errors in my code please let me know (especially commas, brackets and semicolons).